# Click event doesn't execute on <object> tag

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an `<object>` within an anchor tag which has an Angular click event attached to it like this:

```
<a (click)="myAction()">
  <object data="/images/icon.svg"></object>
</a>
```

When I click directly on the `<object>` the click event doesn't work, however, when I click on the padding of the anchor tag (or I remove the object and replace it with text or an `<i>` icon), the click event does work. What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<object>`s are separate documents; effectively they are `<iframe>`s.

Use an `<img>` or inline `<svg>` element instead.

Comment: I was able to use an `<object>` on jsfiddle using a `.png` and the event worked without angular. https://jsfiddle.net/qr475nta/

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn The problem doesn't occur in a simple stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3jaa6u Can you recreate?

Comment: Looks like when you use PNG, it works, but SVG is a separate document tree.

Comment: "The HTML <object> element represents an external resource, which can be treated as an image, a nested browsing context, or a resource to be handled by a plugin". So while a browser might be able traverse a svg file but it won't work for an image, pdf, or a swf.

Comment: I can't use an image because I need a hover effect, and `<img>` cant handle that. I also don't want a huge string of `<svg>` if I don't need to in 10 spots in the code.

Comment: @KurtHamilton https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckvdvs?file=src/app/app.component.html I edited the stack to recreate using svg.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn You can adjust the file to support linking by reference: https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can to add a `<script>` tag to the svg that sends a `postMessage` to the parent:

```xml
<svg>
  <script>
    let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    svg.addEventListener('click', () => {
      window.parent.postMessage('questions-click', '*');
    });
  </script>
  <rect>...</rect>
</svg>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('message', event => {
  if (event.data === 'questions-click') {
    // Do something...
  }
});
```

This method isn't ideal, but it does work.

Comment: May be you can have an image map for `<object>` with a single `<area>` spanning whole object. Have a dummy href and prevent default action as href is mandatory for area. Just a thought. But your requirement suggests that an inline svg will be the best solution.